# React Testing Library : Not able to test hidden buttons

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

I have an edit button in my application. After clicking the edit button, the Edit button got disappeared and two new buttons were rendered on that place. (Save and Cancel).

I've to test the save and cancel functionality.
Tried:
**const save = await screen.findByTestId('save')**
After click event is fired.

On Running this getting error that no element is found with save test id.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code to wait for the button to appear:

`await waitFor(() => screen.findByRole('button', {name:/save/i, hidden: true })`

You can also try - `await waitFor(() => screen.findAllByRole('button', {name:/save/i, hidden: true })`

Check here for more info - [React Testing Lib Link](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/byrole/#hidden)

Comment: Can i use like this:const saveButton= await waitFor(() => screen.findByRole('button', {name:/save/i, hidden: true });     click(saveButton)

Comment: I'm not sure but you can try this approach: 
```await waitFor(() => screen.findAllByRole('button', {name:/save/i, hidden: true });
const saveButton = screen.getByRole('button', {name:/save/i, hidden: true });
userEvent.click(saveButton );
```

Once you get the save button then trigger the click event using userEvent

Comment: Not working for me. Throwing timeout. Thanks